# Picking Items from an array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have this array, which hold 12 items, I randomise the array and hope to pick a question out at random, the only problem is nothing comes back and I don't know why, any help?

My array:

```
<array name="OneTimesTables">
    <item>1 x 1 = </item>
    <item>1 x 2 = </item>
    <item>1 x 3 = </item>
    <item>1 x 4 = </item>
    <item>1 x 5 = </item>
    <item>1 x 6 = </item>
    <item>1 x 7 = </item>
    <item>1 x 8 = </item>
    <item>1 x 9 = </item>
    <item>1 x 10 = </item>
    <item>1 x 11 = </item>
    <item>1 x 12 = </item>
</array>
```

My Code for calling the array:

```
CurrectQuestions = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.CurrentQuestion);

final TypedArray MathsArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.OneTimesTables);
ArrayList<Integer> RandomNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
    RandomNumbers.add(i);
}

Collections.shuffle(RandomNumbers);
int i = 0;

final int Question = MathsArray.getResourceId(RandomNumbers.get(i++), -1);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Question " + Question, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
CurrectQuestions.setText(Question);
```

Comment: Use `String.valueOf(Question)` because `Question` is `int`

Comment: Thanks that works, but it only returns a 0? why is that and not 'i' or the value of 'i' in the set array?

Comment: you have to use loop below too  your i=0 and may be at 0th position element is zero.

Comment: Probably due to `int i = 0;` to some different value like `int i = 3;` and check which value showing in TextView

Comment: it says the value changed at i++ is never used, why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the code where you can get random text from the array and you can tweak it to get the shuffle list as well you have choice in front of you,

here is the code, it is also available on [github](https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/activities/list/first/RandomTestActivity.java)

```
public class RandomTestActivity extends Activity {

    private String[] strings;
    private TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_random_test);

        strings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.OneTimesTables);
        textView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.RandomTestActivity_textView);
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.RandomTestActivity_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int count = (new Random()).nextInt(12);
                textView.setText(""+strings[count]);
            }
        });


        initializeUI();
    }

    private void initializeUI() {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for(String item: strings){
            list.add(item);
        }

        Collections.shuffle(list);

        for (String item:list){
            Log.d("TAG",""+item);
        }
    }

}
```

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="activities.list.first.RandomTestActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/RandomTestActivity_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/RandomTestActivity_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> Output
>   [image]

Comment: Thanks @Pankaj Nimgade

Comment: @RexDough, You are welcome, I am glad, that I could help :)